# Upload txt file to server

Tags: oracle-apex

I want create a form to upload files (txt, xls) to the server, not the database.

Does anyone kown any example showing how I can do this?

Comment: What does "to the server, not the database" mean in this context?  Are you trying to write the file to the operating system on the server that is running the database?  Or are you trying to write the file to a middle tier server running OHS?

Comment: Trying to upload a file to a filesystem where apex is.

Comment: I'm still confused.  APEX runs in the database.  Does that mean that you want to write to the file system on the database server?

Comment: No i simple want to upload a file to a folder in the machine, not putting in the database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not getting it.  You answer my question "No", so you do not want to write to the file system on the database server.  But you previously indicated that you did want to write to the file system on the server "where APEX is".  But APEX runs on the database server.  I cannot figure out how those two statements are compatible.  So I'm back to my original question-- do you want to write to the file system on the database server?  Or do you want to write to the file system on the middle tier server running OHS?  Or something else?

Comment: Like i said i want to create a form in apex so i can upload a file to a folder (ex: /home/user/doc/) in a filesystem in the same machine apex is instaled.

Comment: So you do want to write to the file system on the database server?  When I asked that question the last time, you answered "No".

Comment: My mistake the 'no' in my phrase, sorry.  Yes is that what i want.

Comment: OK, so just to be completely clear, you want to write the file to the file system on the database server, correct?

Comment: yes is that what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the file on to the database server's file system, you would first have to [upload the file to the database](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10513_01/doc/appdev.310/e10497/up_dn_files.htm) which it sounds like you are already familiar with.  From there, you can use the [`UTL_FILE` package to write the BLOB to the database server's file system](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ExportBlob9i.php).

Comment: So the part of upload the file to the database can be spiked or must be made ​​mandatory. I didnt need the file on the database.

Comment: @macwadu - Allowing the file to be uploaded to the database is, by far, the easiest solution.  You could write a whole lot of code that re-implemented much of the "upload BLOB to a table" code that APEX provides but wrote it directly to the database server's file system.  But that would be a whole lot of effort unless there is a particular downside to writing the data to an interim table.

Comment: I was asking this because the files have a 20MB or more of size. So you are saying that is much more complicated not uploading to a blob table and not worth the work, write?

Comment: @macwadu - Correct.  Unless the time it takes to write the data to a BLOB column in a table and then write it again to the file system exceeds the maximum latency you can tolerate, it's not worth rewriting APEX's framework for uploading LOBs.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to trye with your answer. Tanks for your help and time